# How to change the maven dependency view layout?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I can see the maven dependency in the idea like this:
[image: dependencies]

but this is not what I want, I want the maven dependency like this:

[image: dependencies view]

I do not know how to do.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: You don't see the 2nd dependency mode in the "maven projects" view ?

Comment: How about a normal tree? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper

Comment: I think the second view is more intuitional and I can get the 2nd view in the older version ot Intellij IDEA, I am just not used to see the conflicts in the first view. @CrazyCoder

Comment: I can't find the 2nd dependency mode... @wargre

Comment: yeah,I know the plugin.I'm asking if I can get the 2nd view.If not I will use the maven helper. @Meo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you cannot display the layout you want (tree layout) because of a bug (or maybe a feature?).

When you are in the maven dependency viewer clicking on the right button does nothing. But if you click on the floppy disk icon (save diagram) and click cancel, you can then right click in the maven dependency viewer and obtain a contextual menu.

You can then choose the layout (Balloon, Circular, Hierarchic Group, Organic, Orthogonal, Directed Orthogonal, Tree).

But the Balloon and Tree layouts are greyed out and you cannot select them.

P.S.: You can also change the layout with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then selecting the second layout item. But you have only access to Circular, Hierarchic Group, Organic, Orthogonal, Directed Orthogonal layouts.

P.S 2: Tested on IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe it's a bug? I can get the 2nd view in the older Intellij IDEA but I can't get it in the latest version.I think the 2nd view is more intuitional.